# Añadir datos a través de un formulario en java

Tags: java, html, jsp, servlets, gradle

tengo un proyecto de java en graddle y ahora mismo tengo lo básico, he creado una clase para hacer la conexión a la base de datos que lo hace correctamente pero a la hora de añadir los datos no me funciona, he creado un servlet con la anotacion /formulario que enlazo en el html en el action.

este es el login:

```
`<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Login</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Formulario de registro</h1>

<form action="/formulario" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <label for="nombre">Nombre:</label>
    <input type="text" id="nombre" name="nombre" required><br><br>

    <label for="apellidos">Apellidos:</label>
    <input type="text" id="apellidos" name="apellidos" required><br><br>

    <label for="fechaNacimiento">Fecha de Nacimiento:</label>
    <input type="date" id="fechaNacimiento" name="fechaNacimiento" required><br><br>

    <label for="nick">Nick:</label>
    <input type="text" id="nick" name="nick" required><br><br>

    <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
</form>


</body>
</html>`
```

y este es el servlet:

```
 `package servlets;

    import bdConfig.databaseConfig;
    
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.sql.Connection;
    import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
    import java.sql.SQLException;
    import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
    
    @WebServlet("/formulario")
    public class FormularioServlet extends HttpServlet {
    
        @Override
        protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
            // Obtener los valores del formulario
            String nombre = request.getParameter("nombre");
            String apellidos = request.getParameter("apellidos");
            String fechaNacimiento = request.getParameter("fechaNacimiento");
            String nick = request.getParameter("nick");
    
            try {
                // Obtener conexión a la base de datos
                Connection connection = databaseConfig.getConnection();
    
                // Preparar la consulta SQL para insertar los datos
                String sql = "INSERT INTO usuarios (nombre, apellidos, fecha_nacimiento, nick) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)";
                PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
    
                // Asignar los valores de los parámetros en la consulta preparada
                statement.setString(1, nombre);
                statement.setString(2, apellidos);
                statement.setString(3, fechaNacimiento);
                statement.setString(4, nick);
    
                // Ejecutar la consulta de inserción
                statement.executeUpdate();
    
                // Cerrar recursos
                statement.close();
                connection.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println("ERROR");
            }
            System.out.println("Correcto");
            response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + "/WEB-INF/views/exito.jsp");
    

        }
    }
    `
```

No se si el problema esta en los directorios, los tengo así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La dependencia .jar del servlet la añadí. He estado probando varias cosas pero no lo consigo y puede que ser algo ajeno al código pero la conexión con la bd me la hace bien, he ejecutado consultas y me las muestra entonces no se donde puede estar el problema.